# Clonar repositorio de Github mediante script en bash no funciona

Tags: linux, git, bash, script, github

Estoy intentando clonar un repositorio de Github mediante git en un script en bash.
He puesto una condicional de si existe el directorio descargas, ya sea Downloads o Descargas, me descargue el repositorio en el directorio correspondiente.
El código quedaría así:

```
if [[ -d /home/$USER/Downloads ]];then
/usr/bin/git clone $urlGit /home/$USER/Downloads/directorioGit > /dev/null 2>&1
elif [[ -d /home/$USER/Descargas ]];then
/usr/bin/git clone $urlGit /home/$USER/Descargas/directorioGit > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Alguien sabe la forma correcta de descargar un repositorio de Github mediante un script en bash?

Comment: Podrias indicarnos que error te dá y con que usuario lo ejecutas?

Comment: Lo ejecuto como root y no me devuelve ningún error :S

Comment: No puedes ver los errores porque el script redirecciona la salida y los errores a /dev/null. Trata removiendo del script las partes que dicen ` > /dev/null 2>&1` y podrás ver los errores. Con esa información tal vez el problema sea más claro.

Comment: "Lo ejecuto como root y no me devuelve ningún error :S ": OK, entonces cual es el problema? Se supone que no hace lo que esperas, pero si no nos dices que hace no te podemos ayudar. Lo único seguro es que no deberías hacerlo como root, ya que esto lo pondría en `/root` y no en tu `$HOME`, pero si no nos dices que hace, no podemos darte solución.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por las respuestas, he encontrado los errores.
Había hecho varias cosas mal.
Primero de todo no hay que meter la URL en una variable, hay que ponerla directamente como parámetro.
Segundo es normal que no me diera errores en la salida porque no entraba directamente dentro del IF dado que "/home/$USER/Downloas o Descargas" no existia puesto que el directorio "root" no existe en /home.
Lo que he hecho es almacenarlo directamente en /root y así funciona.
Dejo el código por aquí por si a alguno le sirve:

```
if [[ ! -d "/$USER/respositorio" ]];then
/usr/bin/git https://github.com/respositorio /$USER/repositorio > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Comment: Creo que es más confiable usar la variable `$HOME` (y aplicaría correctamente para cualquier usuario _incluyendo_ `root`)

Comment: Otra forma que se me ocurrió después es utilizar el comando "logname" y así aunque lo ejecute con el usuario root se descargará en "/home/$(logname)/" por ejemplo